# 'if' statement conditional code not running as expected

Tags: php

I genuinely do not understand how this code is messing up but it just is, I've never ran into anything of the sort so if anyone can explain what is going on i'd be very glad.

The code : `$functions->update("batzz",$functions->getPlayerInfo("batzz"));` runs no matter whether the if condition is met or not, which is starting to get very frustrating.

This is the whole excerpt of code. There is no loop around it, and when it runs, it prints the proper statement but regardless of whether the if is true or false, it runs the update function.

```
if($functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']) == false) {
    $functions->update("batzz",$functions->getPlayerInfo("batzz"));
    echo "Your account has been updated! Visit your page <a href='/osrstracker/name/". $_GET['name'] ."'>here</a>";
} else {
    echo "Oops, either you havess already updated your account within the past 12 hours or we have messed something up!";
}
```

I would love to understand how this possibly could happen, and if I can fix it as it is very annoying!

Code for function : `$functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']) == false`

```
public function checkRecordsExist($dpname){
        $curdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $olddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-12 hour'));
        $this->query("SELECT * FROM stats JOIN accounts ON stats.userid = accounts.id  WHERE accounts.displayName=:dpname AND stats.date BETWEEN '$olddate' AND '$curdate';");
        $this->bind(":dpname",$dpname);
        $result = $this->resultSet();

        if(!empty($result)){
            if($result[0]['rank'] == 1){
                $this->query("SELECT * FROM stats JOIN accounts ON stats.userid = accounts.id  WHERE accounts.displayName=:dpname AND stats.date BETWEEN '$olddate' AND '$curdate';");
                $this->bind(":dpname",$dpname);
                $result2 = $this->resultSet();
                if(empty($result2)){
                    return false;
                }

            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

PDO Object after query being prepared

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
  string(171) "SELECT * FROM stats JOIN accounts ON stats.userid = accounts.id  WHERE accounts.displayName=:dpname AND stats.date BETWEEN '2016-03-19 11:48:36' AND '2016-03-19 23:48:36';"
}
```

Comment: test: `vav_dump($functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']));`

Comment: Returns bool(true) and runs the function.

Comment: Then `if($functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']))` should be the statement. And use another `$_GET['name']` to one that does not exist and try again.

Comment: Have you tried using ===(triple equals) instead of ==(double equals)? If changing the equals sign stays the same, you can just reverse your conditions I guess

Comment: @Xorifelse I don't know why that would fix it but i tried anyway and it hasnt done anything. Ren, I have indeed, doesnt work. =/

Comment: debugging: `var_dump($_GET['name'], $functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']));` before the if statement - does it return bool true when you expect false?

Comment: @Batzz Because logic wise, if `checkRecordsExist` does what we think it does it must work. If it doesn't, the issue is in that function, returning false all the time even while it shouldnt. Unless as @Ryan Vincent is stating that $_GET['name'] is empty.

Comment: @RyanVincent Its returning what is expected, and it prints the correct statements however the function runs no matter what.

Comment: Try to save The output of $functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']) in a new veribale.

Comment: $test = $functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']);

Comment: Please follow the instructions of @RyanVincent, and report back to us.

Comment: If($test == false){ your code}

Comment: I would use: `if (! $functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name'])) { ...`

Comment: @Basti still doesnt work -_-. I tested another random function with it and it didnt run that one so can it be something to do with OOP?

Comment: @trincot like I said earlier, it runs as expected, returning false when it should be false and returns true when its meant to return true.

Comment: @RyanVincent tried it, doesnt work. I dont think its to do with the if since I tried another function and it worked as normal. I dont see its relevance but I've added the code that checks for the IF.

Comment: @Batzz should be work... Did you try this: if( ($functions->checkRecordsExist($_GET['name']) ) == false)

Comment: @Basti yes I have.

Comment: Need to see the compile query. Any chance you could do `$query = "SELECT ...  AND '$curdate';"` and then `var_dump($query)`?

Comment: @Batzz Go and check following functions: `query()`, `resultSet()` and `bind()`. There is a possibility that you are calling your update function somewhere from within them.

Comment: @Tigger its running a prepare function on the statement that roots from the PDO object, ive added what it prints to the main post, at fanatic, no the update function is not called at all. Ryan I've been working on this for like 3 days and have not found a solution, I dont know what else to do =/

Comment: I am going to sleep this off and set it up online tomorrow, ill update it when done.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using == and not === I would wager that you are actually getting a null, empty string or 0 back from that function - something that is equivalent to false but is not a boolean.  If you were to use a "=== false" comparison or reverse order and do a "!== false" "or === true" comparison, that will force check the type to boolean and may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

May not be an answer but too much for a comment. I believe the problem is here:

```
$result = $this->resultSet();

if(!empty($result)){
    if($result[0]['rank'] == 1){
```

I'm thinking that `$result[0]['rank']` is never `1` so you are hitting the `return true` after the second `if` statement.

I suggest checking the result and maybe even re-writing the logic like so:

```
// no result means false.
if (empty($result)){
    return false;
}

// if the result is NOT a match return true (is this correct?)
if ($result[0]['rank'] != 1){
    return true;
}

// must be a matched result, check for a second result
$this->query("SELECT * FROM stats JOIN accounts 
    ON stats.userid = accounts.id
    WHERE accounts.displayName=:dpname AND stats.date 
    BETWEEN '$olddate' AND '$curdate';");
$this->bind(":dpname",$dpname);
$result2 = $this->resultSet();

// invert result of empty() as final return value (is this correct?)
return (! empty($result2));
```